# render displaySIngleElement component onClick react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events

I am pretty new to react and I have been stuck in a problem for quite a good time.

I have a component `DisplayList` that iterates through an array of objects and displays them in a list form. Each object becomes a button. I also have another component to render the single view of each item on the list once the item is clicked.  My problem is that I get to render the single view of all my items at once INSIDE my `displayList` component. All I want is to be able to click on the list item and render another component with ONLY info about the item I clicked on and passing my "project" as the props to it.  what should I do? What is my error?

My `DisplayList` component (the part that matters for this problem):

```
export default class DisplayList extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      displaySingle: false
    };
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      displaySingle: true
    })
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.projects && this.props.projects.length > 0) {
      return (
        <List component="nav">
          {this.props.projects.map(project => (
            <div className="all-content-wrapper" key={project.id}>
              <ListItem button value={project} onClick={this.handleClick}>
                {this.state.displaySingle ?
                  <DisplaySingleItem project={project} /> :
                  null
                }
                <ListItemICon>
                  <img
                    className="single-item-img-in-list-view"
                    src={project.img}
                  />
                </ListItemICon>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just a hint away from doing it the right way:

Change the condition in your onClick() as:

```
onClick={()=>this.handleClick(project.id)}
         { this.state.displayProject_id === project.id ?
           <DisplaySingleItem project={project} /> : 
            null
         }
```

Now define handleClick() as:

```
    handleClick = (project_id) => {
    this.setState({
                displayProject_id: project_id
               })

    }
```

Don't forget to define the initial state in the constructor:

```
this.state = { 
           displayProject_id:null
 };
```

Comment: Yes! This solution worked! I still haven't figured out how to make the other items of the list invisible once one project is clicked but at least this solved my issue with rendering everything at the same time! Thanks!

Comment: 'how to make items invisible?' with the above solution if you click on other item the previous one's DisplaySingleItem closes and thenew one opens. Is this only you wanted?

Comment: Yes, @Raj! It worked perfectly with your suggested solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div className="all-content-wrapper" key={project.id}>
     <ListItem button value={project} onClick={()=>this.handleClick(project)}>
            {this.state.displayProject && this.state.displayProject.id==project.id ?
              <DisplaySingleItem project={project} /> :
              null
            }
            <ListItemICon>
              <img
                className="single-item-img-in-list-view"
                src={project.img}
              />
            </ListItemICon>
    </ListItem>
</div>
```

change your JSX like the above so you pass the current project to `handleClick` and change `handleClick` like the following.

```
handleClick = (project) => {
    this.setState({
      displayProject : project
   })
 }
```

It should now display the `<DisplaySingleItem/>` for the clicked project.

Comment: Thanks @Yunus for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For you to be able to show only the project that was selected it is important that you have a reference to it. Right now your `handleClick()` function does not accept and parameters or data that you can identify the project that was selected.

My solution for you is to pass the `project` as a parameter to `handleClick(project)`. So your code should look like.

```
export default class DisplayList extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      displaySingle: false
    };
  }

  handleClick = (project) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedProject: project, // <- use this state to show your popup or 
                                     // whatever view you're using
      displaySingle: true
    })
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.projects && this.props.projects.length > 0) {
      return (
        <List component="nav">
          {this.props.projects.map(project => (
            <div className="all-content-wrapper" key={project.id}>
              <ListItem button value={project} onClick={() => this.handleClick(project)}>
                {this.state.displaySingle ?
                  <DisplaySingleItem project={project} /> :
                  null
                }
                <ListItemICon>
                  <img
                    className="single-item-img-in-list-view"
                    src={project.img}
                  />
                </ListItemICon>
   )
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @Kavindu for your help!